# Changing colour scheme of python matplotlib python plots

Tags: python, colors, matplotlib, plot, color-mapping

I want to set a colour scheme for my python plots, so that they don't repeat the same colour like they are for A and H in the top plot shown below. (sorry if its difficult to see).
[image]

The code I'm using is simply,

> ax1.plot(sections,A,label='A',linewidth=2)
>   ax1.plot(sections,B,label='B',linewidth=2)
>   ax1.plot(sections,C,label='C',linewidth=2)
>   ax1.plot(sections,D,label='D',linewidth=2)
>   ax1.plot(sections,E,label='E',linewidth=2)
>   ax1.plot(sections,F,label='F',linewidth=2)
>   ax1.plot(sections,G,label='G',linewidth=2)
>   ax1.plot(sections,H,label='H',linewidth=2)

What's the best way to set the colour scheme? Is using the colourmap function? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4):

You can use some colormaps to color your lines, example (here I use the 'jet' colormap):

```
>>> from matplotlib import cm
>>> for i, val in enumerate(cm.jet(linspace(0,1,10))): #different lines
    plt.plot(arange(10), arange(10)+i, color=val, linestyle='-')
```

[image]

To do this in your existing code with minimal changes, just add (And don't forget to change `10` to the number of plots that you have.):

```
for L, C in zip([item for item in ax.get_children() if isinstance(item, matplotlib.lines.Line2D)], cm.jet(linspace(0,1,10))):
    L.set_color(C)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I'm struggling to understand how to use this in the script I have written. Is there a way I could just say something along the lines of   ax1.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap='jet')

Comment: I'm getting an error saying "NameError: name 'matplotlib' is not defined" in your code. I have defined matplotlib earlier using import "matplotlib.pyplot as plt" and "from matplotlib import *" is there something wrong with that?

Comment: Yeah, add `import matplotlib`, of course, :-). But since you have `from matplotlib import *` already, you just need `lines.Line2D` instead of `matplotlib.lines.Line2D`

Comment: What represents the values that cm.jet(x) returns (where x is any number)?

Comment: It returns a list of RGBA color values, in float point numbers from 0 to 1. If `x` is larger than 1, it returns color 'more blue' than `[0, 0, 0.5, 1]`; if `x` is smaller than 0, returns a color 'more red' than `[0.5, 0, 0, 1]`. Not very easy to see, that is the reason you want to provide it with a `x` within 0 and 1.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the color map for a **specific axes** by using the [`set_color_cycle()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_color_cycle) method.

This is a simplified version of the [color cycle demo](http://matplotlib.org/examples/color/color_cycle_demo.html) in the `matplotlib` docs:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi)
offsets = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 4, endpoint=False)
yy = np.transpose([np.sin(x + phi) for phi in offsets])

plt.rc('lines', linewidth=4)

ax = plt.gca()

# Set color cycle for this axes 
ax.set_color_cycle(['c', 'm', 'y', 'k'])

ax.plot(yy)

plt.show()
```

[image: CMYK example]

The other option is to change the global **default color map**. You can do this by either [creating a `matplotlibrc` file](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/customizing.html) and setting `axes.color_cyle` there, or by chaning the running configuration at runtime:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.rcParams['axes.color_cycle'] = ['r', 'g', 'b']
```

You can also use HTML hex notation for specifying colors:

```
ax.set_color_cycle(['#FF0000', '#00FF00', '#0000FF'])
```

For more information on how to specify colors, see the [documentation of the `color``module](http://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html).

The [`matplotlib.cm` module](http://matplotlib.org/api/cm_api.html) is also useful, for example for registering your own color maps.